# Context menu on child element to also show parent context menu

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, contextmenu

I have an "addresses" parent grid with 2 "address" children grids in it: `Origin` and `Destination`. Depending on the context, both child grids can be shown at once, or only one of them, or none. I'd like to add context menus to enable copying the displayed addresses to the clipboard. Right-clicking on the `origin` address should show a "Copy origin address" menu, and right-clicking on the `destination` address should show a "Copy destination address" menu, but I'd also like to allow the user to copy both address at once, so clicking on either address should also show and additional menu, "Copy both addresses".

My first attempt was by adding a "Copy both addresses" context menu to the main grid and then separately adding a "Copy x address" to each child grid, like so:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Copy both addresses" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </Grid.ContextMenu>

    <!-- Origin -->
    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <Grid.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="Copy origin addresses" />
            </ContextMenu>
        </Grid.ContextMenu>
        <TextBlock Text="Origin" />
    </Grid>

    <!-- Destination -->
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="Copy destination addresses" />
            </ContextMenu>
        </Grid.ContextMenu>
        <TextBlock Text="Destination" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

I was thinking that the context menu of the children will be added (merged) to the parent context menu and show both, I was wrong. Seemingly, context menus on children elements overwrite any context menus on the parent element.

So I tried a more manual and messier method of adding a `CompositeCollection` of `MenuItem`s to each child grid with both the current copy menu and the copy both menu, like so:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!-- Origin -->
    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <Grid.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu.ItemsSource>
                    <CompositeCollection>
                        <MenuItem Header="Copy origin addresses" />
                        <MenuItem Header="Copy both addresses" />
                    </CompositeCollection>
                </ContextMenu.ItemsSource>
            </ContextMenu>
        </Grid.ContextMenu>
        <TextBlock Text="Origin" />
    </Grid>

    <!-- Destination -->
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu.ItemsSource>
                    <CompositeCollection>
                        <MenuItem Header="Copy destination addresses" />
                        <MenuItem Header="Copy both addresses" />
                    </CompositeCollection>
                </ContextMenu.ItemsSource>
            </ContextMenu>
        </Grid.ContextMenu>
        <TextBlock Text="Destination" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

But the problem here is that, as said, it's not always that both addresses will show, in such a case I wouldn't want to show "Copy both addresses" at all.

How can I accomplish this (using the MVVM pattern)?

Comment: *Depending on the context, both child grids can be shown at once, or only one of them, or none.* So what is the actual *context* here, i.e. how do you decide whether to show one, two or zero items? You need to hide the items based on this condition.

Comment: @mm8 I'm binding the visibility of each grid to its property in the view model using a `NullToVisibilityConverter`, which collapses the grid if the binded property is null.